# How to do something like this in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

I developed my app for Android and now I'm trying to do it for IOS. I haven't been able to do this http://oi58.tinypic.com/fon3gp.jpg in Xcode. In Android I used linear and relative layouts to accomplish this. What can I use in Xcode to do something similar? Labels? Text view? Table view?

The page in the link above consists of 1 background, 1 logo, 1 button and one text per pharmacy.

Comment: You should use a UITableView with Custom UITableViewCell. Every cell will contains an UIImage and two UILabel). You can use one section in your table view that you called : "Farmacias"

Comment: Looks like a table view to me.  I've done them much more complex than that.

Comment: The title row can be a "section header" cell, or a plain old table cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a UITableView. There are a plenty of tutorials available for you.
Check these :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

or

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/